# How do you make a Firefox complete theme?

Tags: firefox, themes

I've been searching but couldn't find anything. I want to make a complete Firefox them but I can't find the classic.jar anywhere.
I downloaded a complete theme and renamed it as a .zip file, but I can't really see what I'm looking for inside it (I also don't want to use someone else's work).

Where can I find the file that I am suppose to use as suggested here [Mozilla Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_a_Theme?)

Thanks!

P.S. I'm using Firefox 26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be better to ask Complete Theme related questions on [mozillazine Theme Development forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=18), as this is the place where "Complete Theme" people congregate AFAIK.

Anyway, the MDN documentation is a couple of years out of date. Most of the general stuff does still apply, but in particular the `classic.jar` bits are out of date for a couple of years.

Instead recent Firefox versions use two `omni.ja` files:

- The root is *usually* `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Mozilla Firefox` on Windows, `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/` on OSX, and whereever your Linux/BSD/whatever package manager puts stuff.
- [`omni.ja`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29) files are zip files. But the format is a bit abused to enable certain optimizations, so picky unzippers may reject them.
- `omni.ja` in the root of the installation: This is where `toolkit` and some other common code and styles are located now (Stuff that is common to different mozilla-based applications such as Firefox, Thunderbird, Seamonkey or Instantbird).
- `browser/omni.ja`: Firefox stuff.
- What you need to reconstruct the full theme from these zips, leaving out the non theme code, are the `skin` directories and the `skin` lines of the chrome.manifest files and maybe some `override` lines as well. I would suggest you look at least at the structure and `chrome.manifest` of the released complete themes to get an idea on how to piece this stuff together again.

You should also keep in mind that there is not just one Firefox base theme. There are actually three Desktop Firefox base themes (Windows, OSX, Linux/GTK), that differ quite a lot. So e.g. just taking a theme on Windows, modifying it and releasing it will likely yield unexpected results in e.g. OSX Firefox. Also, even the base themes may have overrides kicking in depending on the OS version: E.g. the Windows theme has different icons for XP and Vista/7 and the OSX theme uses some different icons and styles on OSX Lion and later.

You can browse the theme code online as well: [`toolkit`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/themes/), [`browser`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/themes/)